# Downloaded Javascript photo gallery doesn't work on my site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried to use a number of pre-written javascript photo galleries for our website, but while they work on the source site, I'm failing to get them to work on mine.  It's obviously something basic, but I'm just not seeing it.  The latest pre-written script I've tried is at https://codepen.io/maulikdarji/pen/WwqdMO/ , I've copied the html into my web page as below, modified only by taking out extraneous text and changing the images:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class=""><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/newpage.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Head" -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="Dunlaw.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="slide.js"></script>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">

<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="8%" align="center" valign="bottom">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="84%" align="center"><span class="Head1"> </span>
      <p><a href="The Trust.html">The Trust </a>&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="Applying.html">Applying</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="Awards.html">Awards</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="Trustees.html">Trustees</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="Links.html">Links</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="Contacts.html">Contacts</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="index.html">Home</a> </p>
       </p>
       <p><img src="windfarm.jpg" alt="Dun Law windfarm"> </p>
       <p class="Head1">  DUN LAW TRUST </p>

       <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Titleregion" -->

       <div id="Titlediv">Image Gallery</div>
       <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->

    <td width="8%" align="right" valign="baseline">
  </tr>
</table>


<div id="LayoutDiv2"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Main_region" -->
<hr>

<div id="gallery" class="container-fluid">  

  <img src="images/1.JPG" class="card img-responsive">
  <img src="images/2.JPG" class="card img-responsive">
  <img src="images/3.JPG" class="card img-responsive">
  <img src="images/1.jpg" class="card img-responsive">
  <img src="images/2.jpg" class="card img-responsive">
  <img src="images/3.JPG" class="card img-responsive">
  <img src="images/1.JPG" class="card img-responsive">
  <img src="images/2.JPG" class="card img-responsive">
  <img src="images/3.JPG" class="card img-responsive">

</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I've added the css text to a css file, and made up a file with the js script which I've named 'slide.js' and called from the html page (at other's suggestions, I've tried calling it in the header, body, and at the end, with no joy).

The script works fine on the source site, showing a large image when you click on the gallery, but doesn't do a thing on my site at http://s752783569.websitehome.co.uk/slideshow.html

I'd be grateful for any pointers as to my newbie failings...

Comment: Press F12 and fix console errors

Comment: You need jquery

Comment: mplungjan and Jeremiah Cabigting are both right. You need to [add jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/) and then open the console and look for errors. If you can't figure out how to fix a specific error, then you can bring that to us. If you do, be sure to post the exact error as it appears in the console. Also please post your javascript in slide.js as part of your question.

Comment: You beautiful people.   Thanks to all for that - all pretty much fixed, bar some prettying-up by adding <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> to the web page header.